# WordPress site showing "This page isn't working" after installing it on Amazon EC2 (Linux) Instance via the Duplicator Plugin installer

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-ec2

So I configured My FREE Amazon EC2 (Linux) server with PHP and MySQL using SSH. Then Installed WordPress and set it up accordingly. Which went smoothly and could access perfectly through my "IP/directoryname". After that I had a lot of issues with writing directories and Transferring files. Which I took care of using these commands,

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

Increased the PHP Upload limit using SSH to 256M. And when my test site was running perfectly, I decided to install a Prebuilt site of mine using the Duplicator Plugin which has an installer.php file with the "Old Site Files and Database" a package. It requires an empty directory. So I deleted all my files using FTP from my test site Directory and uploaded the Duplicator Package and Installer. Installed the site and put my EC2 mysql info accordingly. I selected to overwrite my old Database and delete all existing tables. Which installed successfully (At least the installer said that!). But I can't seem to access my site anymore. Now my site says, "This page isn't working". I don't know what to do here. Can you guys spare me a little bit of your time. Any info you need , just ask. Could this be a WordPress Permalink issue? I don't know how to update the Permalink table using SSH. Maybe I've deleted an important Directory file when I deleted the Old Directory files?

Your Friendly Neighborhood Sidekick,

Ratul

Comment: try pasting this on top of your index.php
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
this might tell you a tiny bit more than this page is not working. Remember to remove this after youa re done with debugging

Comment: This totally took me to the right track. Thanks a lot man. As you can see, I'm fairly new to this and trying to learn as much as I can. Actually the issue was caused because of a Plugin of mine and had nothing to do with the EC2 Instance.